# Convert Excel to JSON Array to upload to SQL Server

Tags: json, sql-server, excel, vb.net

I have an Excel spreadsheet that has a couple of columns formatted as currency. I take that spreadsheet and convert it to JSON like this:

```
[{"Date":"5/31/18","Project ID":"2070","Project Description":"Director's Program","Beginning Balance":"$0.00 ","Adjustments":"$0.00 ","Net Change":"$0.00 ","Ending Balance":"$0.00 "},{"Date":"5/31/18","Project ID":"2327","Project Description":"Bone Marrow Transplant","Beginning Balance":"$3,053.84 ","Adjustments":"$0.00 ","Net Change":"$117.89 ","Ending Balance":"$3,171.73 "}
```

using in a VB.NET web service (ASMX)

```
      Dim JObject = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(Of Resultslist())(JSONString)
```

I send the string to a web service that has the a class that changes it into a class

```
<JsonProperty(PropertyName:="Beginning Balance")>
Public Property Beginning() As Decimal
```

What I want to do is to send this to a stored procedure, but I'm getting error of converting a string to a decimal

```
    command.Parameters.Add("@Beginniing", SqlDbType.Money).Value = JObject(i).Beginning
```

And the datatype in the SQL Server database is `Money`. So Excel calls it Currency the JSON wants to make it a string the web service is a decimal and the database is `Money`. I have limited access to the Excel spreadsheet and maybe able to change the data type if that is the only recourse but I would like to stay away from that if possible.

Should I make everything a string and cross my fingers? Ouch and HELP- thanks

Comment: If you remove the currency symbol then it will probably convert without issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you remove the currency symbol it will probably work without error (It really helps to post the actual error in your question)

```
command
.Parameters
.Add("@Beginniing", SqlDbType.Money)
.Value = JObject(i).Beginning.Replace("$","");
```

You're always going to have trouble with excel as a source though - it's a format that invites invalid data.

Comment: Thanks that did the trick.  Sorry about not posting error but it was coming from my ajax command that I could read by hover over the success/error area.  Totally agree with you about Excel but working for a Medical University I have no control over how the data is supplied.  I'm just glad that it's not in a PDF, which some reports from the NIH are